# UISegmentControl - Unable to drag event to a function

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am going through a iOS Programming tutorial using Xcode 8.1. Everything is going well until I needed to add a valueChanged event to the uisegmentcontrol element. When I drag it to bind to the function it does not work. Here is the gif I made that could explain better. Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

[image]

Edit: Here is another gif of the actual tutorial that shows how the event is bound to the function. The full video can be found here [actual tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyR8w6zmxVc). Thank you

[image]

Comment: You cant drag the function into another function...

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: No it has not been solved. Tj3n suggested that I can't drag the valueChanged event to the function. I don't understand because this is what  is shown in the tutorial that you can see in the last gif and the video link I provided. Is it because I am using Xcode 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

I think you not set the class name of the scene.

E.g.

Name of Class for the Scene: ViewController.m

[image]

set StoryboardID if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I just figure out that Xcode now add the parameter Any to all the functions generated. So to be able to bind the event to the function, I needed to change the parameter to AnyObject. I hope it helps someone else in the same situation. :)